# How to get elements with inverted indices in a Julia vector?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have this random vector:

```
julia> rnd = rand(1:100, 1000);
```

And I have Boolean indices related to `rnd` like this:

```
julia> idx = rand(0:1, 1000);
```

If I say `rnd[idx]`, it will return the `rnd`'s elements where the `idx==1` in that indices. But, I want to get the elements where the `idx==0` efficiently!

So I tried these:

```
julia> rnd[~idx]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ~(::Vector{Int64})

julia> rnd[replace(idx, 0=>1, 1=>0)]
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1000-element Vector{Int64} at index [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0  …  1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

julia> rnd[findall(==(0), idx)]
511-element Vector{Int64}:
 70
 31
 43
  ⋮
```

Apparently, the last one works. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Although the post says `rnd[idx]` works to select `1` elements. I'm doubtful, as it is suppose to be Bool and not Int. `idx = rand(Bool, 1000)` sounds more appropriate. In which case, `rnd[.!idx]` gets the `false` indexed elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Int`s for logical indexing. The premise in your question is wrong, which you can see by trying your own code:

```
julia> rnd = rand(1:100, 1000);
julia> idx = rand(0:1, 1000);
julia> rnd[idx]
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1000-element Vector{Int64} at index [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0  …  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

So this fails even before you try to do logical negation. Many programming languages treats 0 and 1 as logicals, but Julia does not.

Instead, do this:

```
julia> idx = rand(Bool, 1000);
julia> rnd[idx];  # works
julia> rnd[.!idx];  # works
```

Or use an even more efficient `BitVector`:

```
julia> using Random: bitrand
julia> idx = bitrand(1000);
julia> typeof(idx)
BitVector (alias for BitArray{1})
julia> rnd[idx];  # works
julia> rnd[.!idx];  # works
```

A `BitVector` is a highly efficient structure, at least storagewise, since it only uses one bit per value. It is also very commonly used for logical indexing.

The dot in front of the not-operator is also necessary to broadcast it over the vector. You can not logically negate a vector, but you can do it elementwise, for which you need the dot.

As for `!` vs `~` (which I see you are using), they will do the same thing here, but they are not quite the same. `~` is the 'bitwise not', it flips the bits in a value, like this:

```
julia> bitstring(0x7)
"00000111"
julia> bitstring(~0x7)
"11111000"
```

For booleans this amounts to the same as logical not. `!` on the other hand, is actual logical not. This is the 'correct' choice for doing logical negation on Bools.

(BTW, if you use `~` on integers, you may be surprised:

```
julia> ~0
-1
julia> ~1
-2
```

)

Comment: Thanks, It's absolutely better than my answer ❤️ I always try to learn from you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`InvertedIndices`](https://github.com/JuliaData/InvertedIndices.jl) package, and in particular `Not`:

```
julia> rnd = rand(1:100, 3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 66
 52
 18

julia> idx = rand(Bool, 3)
3-element Vector{Bool}:
 0
 1
 1

julia> rnd[Not(idx)]
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 66
```